# Program (twitter bot) works on Windows machine, but not on Linux machine

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean

I am making a twitter bot and when I run the program on my windows computer it works perfectly fine. I moved it to a Linux server (Ubuntu 14.04) I'm leasing from Digital Ocean and I get the following error:

[image]

I believe the error means there is some character that python or linux doesn't like.

Here is **the piece of code referenced by the error:**

```
    def DTcomment(self, c, comment):
    comment = ['\0'] * 141
    c2 = 0
    with open('DTquotes.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            while line[c] != '~':
                comment[c2] = line[c]
                c2+=1
                c+=1

    stringComment = ATS(comment)
    c+=1
    return c, stringComment
```

(Just fyi, the ATS function is just changing an array to a string)

My program already skips any tweets if they have emoji's in them.

**So my question is:** why am I receiving this error? and how can I fix it?

EDIT: I don't think this is a duplicate question. I did not ever use Python 2.4. I only used Python3.4 on Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: Please do not post code and output as images. It makes it hard for others to copy to try for themselves or to quote in a comment/answer. Paste them into the question as text.

Comment: Also, the bold text is not necessary

Comment: The code is one method I have in my program. Not sure if you'll be able to run it properly. I'll post it as code in a second, though. @cricket_007 I removed most of the bold text. Also, let's try and refrain from any posts that aren't constructive towards the solution, please and thank you!

Comment: I use python3.4 in both OS's, so I don't think that is the problem.